# Labeling at M value vertices only?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, linear-referencing, measurements

How would one label at M value vertices only?

We have added M values using linear referencing and now would like to label stations at the vertices.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what M value vertices are, but I think that what you are asking can all be done with in ArcMap with Label Expressions.  Here are some links showing you all the various possibilities that label expressions will allow you to do.  Specifically I would look at the if then statements and the like.

http://christopherwesson.azurewebsites.net/2013/12/09/some-handy-arcgis-label-expressions/#sthash.yQH514OA.dpbs

https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1104/files/vbscript_label.pdf

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a point feature class using [Feature Vertices To Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000).
2. Add M-values as an attribute using [Add XY](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000032000000) tool
3. Label points using POINT_M attribute

Reference:
[article](http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40711)

Comment: I had thought of creating a point FC, but am looking for a way to not have to do that.  I'd like to label the vertices as I'm trying to avoid maintaining another FC.